# mongoDB C# Driver is not returning any data

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver, document, bson

I am having a problem where C# Driver is not returning any data with either using **async-await** or **synchronous** method.

When trying to run in the command line, it works perfectly, here's the snippet:

```
db.Collection_StudentResults.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$modules" }, { $match: { "studentNumber": "", "modules.code": "" } } ])
```

and here's how I have it setup in C#:

```
public static async Task<BsonDocument> getSingleStudentData(string studentNumber)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("dbStudents");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Collection_StudentResults");

        var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
            .Unwind("modules")
            .Match(new BsonDocument { { "studentNumber", studentNumber } });

        var result = await aggregate.ToListAsync();

        return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Drivers Used: **v2.4.0**
MongoDB Version: **v3.2.10**

In **Collection_StudentResults**, the first document contains the **studentNumber** and **modules** array, in the **modules** array each document has **code** field.

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - my bad, bad bad bad...

I missed the db = db.getSiblingDB in my builder script - which caused the data to go into the root database.

All the best.